# Why is a Vec of boxed closures not sized when calling Rayon's into_par_iter?

Tags: rust, rayon

I have a `Vec` of boxed closures (`Vec<Box<Fn(...) -> ...>>`). I can do `vec.into_iter().map(...)`, but I can't use it with Rayon's [`into_par_iter`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#tymethod.into_par_iter) `vec.into_par_iter().map(...)`.

Here's a minimised example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=171c65449c60985543c543582fccd93f)):

```rust
type GameResult<T> = Result<T, ()>;
type Game = ();
type PlayerId = String;

use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1

fn main() {
    // the type of our closures. It's boxed, so it's sized right?
    type CpuOption = Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> GameResult<u32>>;
    let mut options: Vec<CpuOption> = vec![];

    options.push(Box::new(|i| Ok(i + 2)));
    options.push(Box::new(|i| Ok(i + 3)));

    let try_it = |option: CpuOption| -> GameResult<u32> { Ok(option(12)?) };

    let parallel = true;

    if parallel {
        // ERROR IS HERE. says my type isn't sized?
        let options = options
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(try_it)
            .flat_map_iter(Result::into_iter);
        let best_option = options.max_by_key(|score| *score).unwrap();
    } else {
        // but this works fine!
        let options = options.into_iter().map(try_it).flat_map(Result::into_iter);
        let best_option = options.max_by_key(|score| *score).unwrap();
    }
}
```

The error that I get:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0599]: the method `into_par_iter` exists for struct `Vec<Box<(dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()> + 'static)>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:24:14
   |
24 |             .into_par_iter()
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<Box<(dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()> + 'static)>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `[Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()>>]: Sized`
           which is required by `[Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()>>]: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
           `[Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()>>]: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
           which is required by `[Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()>>]: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
```

I was under the impression that wrapping the closure in the box was the solution to making closures be sized so I've done that here.

If I read the error right, `[Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Result<u32, ()>>]: Sized` isn't met and it's a prerequisite for `IntoParallelIterator` which is the piece I'm after. The regular `into_iter()` works fine so there's some additional constraint that Rayon is placing. I expected Rayon to have more constraints but I assumed that it would be something about `Send`

I know in this minimal example I could use `fn(...)` types instead of `Fn(...)` types because they don't capture any values but of course my real code does capture references.

I'm using Rayon to write the AI for a little game using a minimax style where I have a list of things for the AI to try and I then observe the score after each of those things. I want the top-level of this recursive call stack to start the top level in many threads but each thread should be sequential.

Comment: `[AnyPossibleType]` is not sized.

Comment: @Shepmaster where is that type coming from though? I don't have any raw array types in my code and I assume Rayon works so it's not just a fundamental thing that Rayon makes raw array types so can't ever work.

Comment: That's not an array; arrays are `[T; N]`. It is a slice (compared to a slice reference `&[T]` or a boxed slice `Box<[T]>`).

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11cb98157986bc989b2f57d10764daae). Specifically: `type CpuOption = Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> GameResult<u32> + Send>;`. TL;DR your closures cannot be sent between threads and [`impl<T: Send> IntoParallelIterator for Vec<T>`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#impl-IntoParallelIterator-for-Vec%3CT%3E).

Comment: It is strange that `IntoParallelIterator::into_par_iter(options);` gives you a better error message but when you call `options.into_par_iter` probably compiler tried to find the closest implementation without `Send`

Comment: @Shepmaster If the problem is just in the missing `Send` bound, why is the compiler complaining about missing `Sized`? Is that a flaw in diagnostics or a weird interaction with some other language feature that throws off the compiler (and would make the diagnostic legitimate in other situations)?

Comment: @user4815162342 I'd guess it's close to what Ömer Erden said — the compiler has a giant list of possible types that implement the required traits and it has to decide which of those to include in the error message. I'm guessing that `[T]` counts as "getting closer" and is usually the better thing to show. I'd say that it is indeed a diagnostics issue, but I shudder to think how the compiler could be changed to do better...